# PhantomJS not returning complete response

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to get response from the below URL using PhantomJS.  But it seems that PhantomJS not loading the javascript code that is being run when the page is being opened normally in a browser.

```
http://www.marriott.com/reservation/availabilitySearch.mi?isSearch=false&fromDate=06/05/2017&toDate=06/06/2017&clusterCode=&corporateCode=&groupCode=&numberOfRooms=1&numberOfGuests=1&incentiveType_Number=&incentiveType=false&marriottRewardsNumber=&useRewardsPoints=false&propertyCode=NYCCP
```

I am using the below code:-

```
function onPageReady() {
    var htmlContent = page.evaluate(function () {
        return document.documentElement.outerHTML;
    });

    console.log(htmlContent);

    phantom.exit();
}

page.open(url, function (status) {
    function checkReadyState() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var readyState = page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.readyState;
            });

            if ("complete" === readyState) {
                onPageReady();
            } else {
                checkReadyState();
            }
        });
    }

    checkReadyState();
});
```

But I am not getting complete HTML response. Can somebody help me on this ?